# Pandas: go through column and if nan value appears, send the remaning column values to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

In case I have a dataframe as

```
Index     values
1          2
2          4
3          3
4          nan
5          nan
6          nan
7          9 
8          7
9          8
10         nan
11         5
12         1
13         6
```

How can I set new columns in a new dataframe for each vector with values different than nan?
The solution would something like the following:

```
Index     values_1     values_2     values_3
1            2            9            5
2            4            7            1
3            3            8            6
```

Comment: What happens if the number of values is different? For example add a new row after the last 8 of the second group?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can get the `cumsum()` of values that are null to separate into groups, which is how you create columns. This works because it returns `False` for non-null rows, so when you take the `cumsum()`, you get the first group all as group `0`, and the other groups will be separated into different group IDs as well.
2. Null rows were used for logic of step 1, but are no longer needed so use `dropna()`
3. Now, you reset the group numbers, so they are 1,2,3 with `(df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift())).cumsum()`
4. You also have to create a new index using `df1.groupby('col1').cumcount() + 1`, in order fror the rows to be on the same line.
5. Then, just `pivot` defining an `index` and `columns`.
6. Finally, clean up the column names into one level with the last line of code.

---

```
# df1 = df1.drop('Index', axis=1) #include this line of code if "Index" is a column. Otherwise, omit.
df['col1'] = (df['values'].isnull().cumsum())
df = df.dropna()
df['col1'] = (df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift())).cumsum()
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1').cumcount()
df = (df.pivot(index='col2', columns='col1').reset_index(drop=True)
        .add_prefix('values_').droplevel(0, axis=1))
# can also use # df.columns = [f'{col[0]}_{col[1]}' for col in df.columns] # instead of # .add_prefix('values_').droplevel(0, axis=1))
df
Out[1]: 
   values_1  values_2  values_3
0       2.0       9.0       5.0
1       4.0       7.0       1.0
2       3.0       8.0       6.0
```

Comment: @Manakin that is true. I would also have to do `.droplevel(0, axis=1)` e.g. `.add_prefix('values_').droplevel(0, axis=1)`

Comment: I'm getting an error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'droplevel'. I've tried with python 3.5 and 3.7. Pandas version is 0.23.4

Answer (score 2):

we can use a boolean to create a new index then use `unstack` and `add_prefix`

```
df['key'] = ((df['values'].isna()==True) & 
            (df['values'].shift(1).isna()==False)).cumsum() + 1

df = df.dropna()

df1 = df.set_index([df.groupby(['key']).cumcount(),'key'])\
        .unstack(1)\
        .add_prefix('values_')\
        .droplevel(0,1)


print(df1)

key  values_1  values_2  values_3
0         2.0       9.0       5.0
1         4.0       7.0       1.0
2         3.0       8.0       6.0
```

Comment: Nice +1, a little bit cleaner than mine (which I have fixed now :) )

Comment: @FJ35 you're very welcome. don't forget to accept the answer that helps you most - I would suggest David's as he put in a large amount of detail for you

Comment: I'm getting an error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'droplevel'. I've tried with python 3.5 and 3.7. Pandas version is 0.23.4

Comment: @FJ35 droplevel comes into the pandas API from 0.24 can you upgrade ?